# SwiftUI mutilple line text not handling/alinging properly in Vstack

Tags: ios, user-interface, text, swiftui, vstack

I'm facing alignment issue when text input is multiple lines. In this example, first image shows left and right side text is properly shown. second image, it shows when we long text it takes 3 to 4 lines which disturb alignment on the left and right side as well.

I want to make left make independently size adjust which can maximum 5 line and right side remain as it is(no gap on top and bottom side).

Comment: Please explain it more with a sketch of what you need to achieve 

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem, but if you want to align the smaller text for example to the top you need to change HStack alignment top top instead of center, if this is not you problem, please explain it more with a sketch of what you need to achieve

```
HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top, spacing: 0)
```

[image]

Comment: mai pa has address question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Shown in second image, I want right side position to be always top. Right now, on left side it shows 3 line so it’s changing alignment on both side which is bad. Alignment only limits on left side

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).